# [DevStack][Ceilometer][Gnocchi] Error 403

Tags: devstack, ceilometer

I am currently on an Openstack Project and I'm trying to use Ceilometer and Gnocchi. I've installed DevStack with the following lines in the `local.conf` file to install and configure Ceilometer and Gnocchi:

```
enable_plugin gnocchi https://github.com/gnocchixyz/gnocchi master
enable_plugin ceilometer https://git.openstack.org/openstack/ceilometer
enable_service gnocchi-grafana
```

The installation was successful, the Metric service has been created along with the ceilometer and gnocchi users. The `[keystone_authtoken]` sections of the Ceilometer and Gnocchi configuration files are apparently correctly set, I set Gnocchi as the meter dispatcher in the Ceilometer config file.

But with commands related to the `metric`argument like `openstack metric status` I get a 403 error, though I sourced the `admin-openrc.sh` file before. I tried with both versions 2.0 and 3 API.

I thought that adding the admin user as a member and admin of the `service` project in OpenStack would solve the problem, but I'm still getting the error.

I looked through the Apache logs involving Gnocchi:
- in `/var/log/apache2/gnocchi.log` there is the "client denied by server configuration: /usr/local/bin/gnocchi-api" error,
- in `var/log/apache2/gnocchi-acces.log` there are 403 errors like this:

```
10.0.3.29 - - [28/Jul/2017:16:24:34 +0300] "POST /v1/batch/resources/metrics/measures?create_metrics=True HTTP/1.1" 403 501 "-" "ceilometer-agent-notification keystoneauth1/3.1.0 python-requests/2.18.2 CPython/2.7.12"
10.0.3.29 - - [28/Jul/2017:16:24:34 +0300] "PATCH /v1/resource/image/bc130fad-36f6-48a5-852b-b78e41863d09 HTTP/1.1" 403 520 "-" "ceilometer-agent-notification keystoneauth1/3.1.0 python-requests/2.18.2 CPython/2.7.12"
```

Is it any misconfigurations I didn't notice?

If you want any more information, just ask me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer from Q&A of OpenStack [here](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/108789/403-forbidden-gnocchi-api/):

Following config for `/etc/apache2/sites-available/gnocchi.conf` works fine at this moment:

```
Listen 8041

<VirtualHost *:8041>
    WSGIDaemonProcess gnocchi lang='en_US.UTF-8' locale='en_US.UTF-8' user=stack display-name=%{GROUP} processes=2 threads=32
    WSGIProcessGroup gnocchi
    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/bin/gnocchi-api
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        ErrorLogFormat "%{cu}t %M"
    </IfVersion>


    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/gnocchi.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gnocchi-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/apache2
```

After `service apache2 restart` output for command `gnocchi status` is following:

```
$ gnocchi status
+-----------------------------------------------------+-------+
| Field                                               | Value |
+-----------------------------------------------------+-------+
| storage/number of metric having measures to process | 0     |
| storage/total number of measures to process         | 0     |
+-----------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Not like before:

```
$ gnocchi status
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /v1/status
on this server.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 10.92.76.44 Port 8041</address>
</body></html>
 (HTTP 403)
```